# jquery integer post ajax php -> unrecognized expression 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following,

```
var i = 0;
$('.more').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data{"num":i},
    url:theurl,
    success:function(html){
        $container.append(html);
        i = i+18;
```

etc.  When I POST the data and in PHP echo $_POST['num']; I am getting the error "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 0" and a bunch of html following it.  When I don't include the data with the number 0 it works fine.  Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If the argument to `append` doesn't begin with an HTML tag, it's treated as a jQuery selector. You should either wrap it in a DIV:

```
$container.append("<div>" + html + "</div>");
```

or use `.html()` instead of `.append()`

```
$container.html(function(i, oldhtml) {
    return oldhtml + html;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this was my attempt at applying pagination to the masonry cascading grid layout.  I'm sure your method will work, but I was incrementing the values and POST'ing to perform a SQL query and get the next set of 18 objects.  I'm starting to think there is a better way to do this...

Comment: Why are you echoing `$_POST['num']` in the PHP in the first place? That's what's causing the problem, it's not part of the HTML you want to display.

Comment: I don't know friend, I thought I could echo POST data separately from the HTML I am passing.  I echo'd it to see if it was there, which it is.  But I would like to use this value in my SQL query, sanitized of course.

Comment: Ok, guess I'm still a noob.  I used the value in a query and it worked fine.  Thank you for your time.